# Refresh react-native-maps polyline

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm adding a polyline to the MapView with:

```
<MapView.Polyline
      ref={polylineref => {
        this.savePolylineRef(polylineref);
      }}
      coordinates={coordinates}
      strokeWidth={3}
      geodesic={false}
      strokeColor={Color.brightGreen}
/>
```

But now I'm stuck because I do not know how to refresh the coordinates of the polyline using the **polylineRef**. I've tried `polylineRef.coordinates` and `polylineRef._component.coordinates`, but both seems non existent…

I'm I missing something or is this not the correct way of refreshing the polyline?

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just set `coordinates` from state, and then just update state which will re-render your Polyline?

Comment: That is what I'm doing, but it's leading to a memory leak. My guess is that on every reload a new map object is being created…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MapPolyline](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/components/MapPolyline.js) has a function "setNativeProps" which is accepting props

Try this

```
polylineRef.setNativeProps({coordinates:newCoordinates}})
```

Note: replace "newCoordinates" with coordinates you want to apply